# JTDS and Transactions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, transactions, jtds

I see different behaviors when I call a stored procedure (MSSQL 2008R2) directly from SSMS or when I call it from JTDS.

First, please see these two procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Template].[UnguardedTest]
    @outparam_StartTransactionCount INT OUTPUT,
    @outparam_TransactionCount INT OUTPUT 

AS

BEGIN 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @StartTranCount INT

    SELECT @StartTranCount = @@TRANCOUNT

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    BEGIN
        SELECT @outparam_StartTransactionCount = @StartTranCount
        SELECT @outparam_TransactionCount = @@TRANCOUNT
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

The second is very similar to the first, except it will not begin (nor commit) a transaction except if the `@@TRANCOUNT` on entry is 0.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Template].[GuardedTest]
   @outparam_StartTransactionCount INT OUTPUT,
   @outparam_TransactionCount INT OUTPUT 

AS

BEGIN 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @StartTranCount INT

    -- Record the @@TRANCOUNT at the beginning of this procedure / trigger.
    SELECT @StartTranCount = @@TRANCOUNT

    IF @StartTranCount = 0
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

    BEGIN
        SELECT @outparam_StartTransactionCount = @StartTranCount
        SELECT @outparam_TransactionCount = @@TRANCOUNT
    END

    IF @StartTranCount = 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

If I call them from SSMS, with the code below

```
DECLARE @outparam_TransactionCount INT
DECLARE @outparam_StartTransactionCount INT

EXECUTE [Template].[UnguardedTest] @outparam_StartTransactionCount OUTPUT, @outparam_TransactionCount OUTPUT
SELECT 'UNGUARDED_NOT_WRAPPED' AS Description, @outparam_StartTransactionCount AS [StartTranCount],  @outparam_TransactionCount AS [TranCount]

BEGIN TRAN
    EXECUTE [Template].[UnguardedTest] @outparam_StartTransactionCount OUTPUT, @outparam_TransactionCount OUTPUT
    SELECT 'UNGUARDED_WRAPPED' AS Description, @outparam_StartTransactionCount AS [StartTranCount],  @outparam_TransactionCount AS [TranCount]
COMMIT TRAN

EXECUTE [Template].[GuardedTest] @outparam_StartTransactionCount OUTPUT, @outparam_TransactionCount OUTPUT
SELECT 'GUARDED_NOT_WRAPPED' AS Description, @outparam_StartTransactionCount AS [StartTranCount],  @outparam_TransactionCount AS [TranCount]

BEGIN TRAN
    EXECUTE [Template].[GuardedTest] @outparam_StartTransactionCount OUTPUT, @outparam_TransactionCount OUTPUT
    SELECT 'GUARDED_WRAPPED' AS Description, @outparam_StartTransactionCount AS [StartTranCount],  @outparam_TransactionCount AS [TranCount]
COMMIT TRAN
```

The output is what I'd expect.

```
Description           StartTranCount TranCount
--------------------- -------------- -----------
UNGUARDED_NOT_WRAPPED 0              1

Description       StartTranCount TranCount
----------------- -------------- -----------
UNGUARDED_WRAPPED 1              2

Description         StartTranCount TranCount
------------------- -------------- -----------
GUARDED_NOT_WRAPPED 0              1

Description     StartTranCount TranCount
--------------- -------------- -----------
GUARDED_WRAPPED 1              1
```

That is wrapping the call to the procedure within a transaction causes the StartTranCount to be 1, otherwise, it is zero.

However, when I execute the same procedures via JTDS/JDBC, as per the code below, I see strange behavior.

```
    int tc = -1, startTC = -1;

    final Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    con2.setAutoCommit(false);
    final CallableStatement proc2 = con2.prepareCall("{ call Template.GuardedTest(?,?) }");
    proc2.registerOutParameter("@outparam_StartTransactionCount", Types.INTEGER);
    proc2.registerOutParameter("@outparam_TransactionCount", Types.INTEGER);
    proc2.execute();
    startTC = proc2.getInt("@outparam_StartTransactionCount");
    tc = proc2.getInt("@outparam_TransactionCount");
    log.info("Guarded StartTC: " + startTC + ", TC: " + tc);
    proc2.close();          
    con2.commit();
    con2.close();

    final Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    con1.setAutoCommit(false);
    final CallableStatement proc1 = con1.prepareCall("{ call Template.UnguardedTest(?,?) }");
    proc1.registerOutParameter("@outparam_StartTransactionCount", Types.INTEGER);
    proc1.registerOutParameter("@outparam_TransactionCount", Types.INTEGER);
    proc1.execute();
    startTC = proc1.getInt("@outparam_StartTransactionCount");
    tc = proc1.getInt("@outparam_TransactionCount");
    log.info("Unguarded StartTC: " + startTC + ", TC: " + tc);
    proc1.close();
    con1.commit();
    con1.close();
```

I'm seeing the following output:

```
- Guarded StartTC: 0, TC: 2
- Unguarded StartTC: 0, TC: 2
```

As I was expecting to see the same values as the 'wrapped' example above (as I understand that JDBC begins a new transaction when calling `setAutoCommit(false)`, I'm really at a loss as to what is going on.   Any insight?

Additional info:

If I switch to the Microsoft JDBC driver, I get the results I expect

```
MSFT Driver - Guarded StartTC: 1, TC: 1
MSFT Driver - Unguarded StartTC: 1, TC: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered the cause of this behavior.

I assumed that jTDS, after `setAutoCommit(false)` was called, was explicitly beginning a transaction for the connection.   In fact, it doesn't behave that way.  What it does do is issue a `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` on the connection.

According to Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx) - "When IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS = ON an explicit BEGIN TRANSACTION will start two nested transactions."

For example, if we execute the following in SSMS

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
    EXECUTE [Template].[UnguardedTest] @outparam_StartTransactionCount OUTPUT, @outparam_TransactionCount OUTPUT
    SELECT 'UNGUARDED_IMPLICIT' AS Description, @outparam_StartTransactionCount AS [StartTranCount],  @outparam_TransactionCount AS [TranCount]
COMMIT TRAN

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
    EXECUTE [Template].[GuardedTest] @outparam_StartTransactionCount OUTPUT, @outparam_TransactionCount OUTPUT
    SELECT 'GUARDED_IMPLICIT' AS Description, @outparam_StartTransactionCount AS [StartTranCount],  @outparam_TransactionCount AS [TranCount]
COMMIT TRAN
```

We get the following:

```
Description        StartTranCount TranCount
------------------ -------------- -----------
UNGUARDED_IMPLICIT 0              2

Description      StartTranCount TranCount
---------------- -------------- -----------
GUARDED_IMPLICIT 0              2
```

which agrees with the output we get when jTDS executes those procedures.